# C# visual basic error decimal

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, facebook, c#-4.0

I have some problem in my code( in our sql database `UnitPrice` and `TotalPrice` data type `decimal` and when I want to add data I got this error
 **"error converting data type varchar to numeric"**

my code:

```
#region EDIT RECORD 
    private bool EditRecord()
    {
        DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle);
        if (row == null) return false;
        PopupChillers frm = new PopupChillers();
        frm.InitData(this.FindForm(), gridControl3, gridView1, row);
        bool ret = frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK;
        if (ret)
        {
            row.ItemArray = frm.Row.ItemArray;
            string DegiskenId;
            DegiskenId = row[0].ToString();

            #region Kaydet guncelle hata kontrolu
            try
            {
                #region Guncelle
                if (KayitSekli == "GUNCELLE")
                {
                    string gsorgu = "UPDATE OrnekTbl SET ProjectName=@ProjectName,UnitPrice=@UnitPrice,TotalPrice=@TotalPrice WHERE ProjectName='" + DegiskenId + "'";
                    objSqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(gsorgu, objSqlConnection);
                    objSqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[0].ToString();

                    objSqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[1].ToString();
                    objSqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalPrice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[2].ToString();

                    {
                        objSqlConnection.Open();
                        objSqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    objSqlConnection.Close();

                }
                #endregion

                #region Kaydet
                if (KayitSekli == "KAYDET")
                {
                    string ksorgu = "INSERT INTO OrnekTBL (ProjectName,UnitPrice,TotalPrice) VALUES (@ProjectName,@UnitPrice,@TotalPrice)";
                    objSqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(ksorgu, objSqlConnection);
                    objSqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[0].ToString();

                    objSqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[1].ToString();
                    objSqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalPrice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[2].ToString();

                    if (objSqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        objSqlConnection.Open();
                        objSqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                objSqlConnection.Close();
            }
            #endregion
            row.EndEdit();

        }
        return ret;
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems pretty clear.  Take a look at your parameters:

```
objSqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[1].ToString();
objSqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalPrice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row[2].ToString();
```

You're explicitly declaring them as `SqlDbType.VarChar`.  The field names, however, suggest that they are numeric values.  (Money?  Decimal?)  The parameters need to match the data types of the columns.  Perhaps something like this:

```
decimal unitPrice = 0;
if (!decimal.TryParse(row[1].ToString(), out unitPrice))
{
    // TODO: Handle the error if it's not a valid decimal
}
objSqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = unitPrice;
```

Comment: thanks for your kind interest but i dont know where i will write this in my code..

Comment: i tried money but i wanna write in colum "UniPrice and Totalprice" like that 1,567,900.56

Comment: @user3198433: It's not clear what you mean by that.  Is "unit price and total price" going to be a column in the database?  I wouldn't advise tracking the same data in multiple columns.  It can be a calculated result in a `SELECT` statement, a view, or even in code.  But *inserting* that value into the database wouldn't be recommended.  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @user3198433 - Why do you want to store the value with commas in the database?  You should use a numeric datatype in the database and then when you display the value, then format with the commas, etc.

Comment: I have 2 columns.. UnitPrice and TotalPrice so I need a this format $1,567.56

Comment: @user3198433: That's a money and/or decimal format.  The actual "$" and "." and "," characters aren't part of the underlying data.  The data is the numeric representation.  The formatting is part of the display, which is in the user interface.  There's absolutely no reason to store a numeric value as a string in the underlying data.